# I am trying to add a code from a book I am following to an existing code I am writing

Tags: android-recyclerview, viewmodel

Open PodcastActivity.kt and add the following lines to the top of the class. This is the question
this is the code I am adding
private val searchViewModel by viewModels()
private lateinit var podcastListAdapter: PodcastListAdapter
This is where I am adding it to
class PodcastActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

```
    // 1
    val inflater = menuInflater
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu)
    // 2
    val searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_item)
    val searchView = searchMenuItem?.actionView as SearchView
    // 3
    val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE)
            as SearchManager
    // 4
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
       searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName)
    )
    return true
    setupToolbar()
}

private fun performSearch(term: String) {
    val itunesService = ItunesService.instance
    val itunesRepo = ItunesRepo(itunesService)
    itunesRepo.searchByTerm(term) {
        Log.i(Companion.TAG, "Results = $it")
    }
}

private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH == intent.action) {
        val query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY) ?: return
        performSearch(query)
    }
}

override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent)
    setIntent(intent)
    handleIntent(intent)
}

companion object {
    private const val TAG = "PodcastActivity"
}

private fun setupToolbar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
}
```

}